# Any option to upgrade library in tinycad?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I used tinycad to draw circuit schematics for my project. But CD 4017 IC was not there in its library. Is there is any possibility to upgrade tinycad library?

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own part symbols in TinyCAD is really easy. The [TinyCAD User Manul (PDF)](http://chowk.khu.ac.kr/lecture/electronic_circuit/Spice_Tool/TintCAD/Tinycad_Manual.pdf) covers it. Have a look at the section "Editing and adding symbols" on page 21.

You might get lucky and find a library for a particular component, but most of the time you won't. Learning to create your own libraries is a pre-requisite to using any even slightly obscure ICs. Once you've done it a few times it's really simple!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it, but such possibility is there for sure.

From the SourceForge page of the project:

> ... It supports standard and custom symbol libraries. ...

Also, https://www.google.com/search?q=tinycad+custom+symbol